# Does our apple tree have crown gall?

Tags: trees, tree-care, apples

We are trying to rehabilitate this apple tree. It is very much alive but had several dead branches, which we have since cut off. It was also invaded by ants, which I hope we have scared away.

We noticed these bumps, are they an indication that the tree is infected by crown gall? The pictures are similar to those I see online, but I'm not sure. There are a good dozen of these bumps or more, starting at ~1.5m up the trunk and down to about 20cm above ground level. FWIW, this tree is in the north of Italy, around 200m above sea level.

If yes - should we cut it down?

If no, are they any cause for concern?

Several higher-quality images available here: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1Mf-ENlWYE0hwFwDlVQgk06bLAxwXLEzJ?usp=sharing

[image]

[image]